# Create function with changing fields (Javascript?)

Tags: javascript, php, crud, contacts

Trying to implement a create function for a contact list.

I want it to function in a way in which the first question asks for a 'contact type' with three fields - individual, team and company.

By selecting one of the fields, the fields below would change. An individual would show all fields (name, company, title, phone, email, address) whereas company would ask for no name/title and team would ask for no title. All these fields + the first question are already rows in mysql.

I have no idea where to start, how the syntax of it should work and how javascript is to be incorporated into this function? And recommendations?

Cheers!

Edit: my bad. So I've got the fields all down.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
<title>Create new contact</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="post" class="form-horizontal col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <h2>Motoko Insurance Contacts</h2>



<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>   
<script> 
$( document ).ready(function() {
listenForInputChanges();
})

function listenForInputChanges() {
$('#contactType >input').change(function(){
 console.log('val is '+$(this).val())
 switch($(this).val()) {
 case 'individual':
$('#nameDiv').show();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').show();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
 break;

  case 'team':
 $('#nameDiv').show();
 $('#companyDiv').show();
 $('#titleDiv').hide();
 $('#phoneDiv').show();
 $('#emailDiv').show();
 $('#addressDiv').show();
 break;

case 'company':
$('#nameDiv').hide();
$('#companyDiv').show();
$('#titleDiv').hide();
$('#phoneDiv').show();
$('#emailDiv').show();
$('#addressDiv').show();
break;
  }
})
}
</script>   

<div class="form-group">
 <label for="input" class="col-sm-2 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type"
value="individual" > Individual
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type"
value="team"> Team
 <input type="radio" name="Contact_type"
value="company"> Company</div>
 </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" 
/>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="comp"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Company" />
            </div>
         </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Title</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="title"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Title" />
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Phone</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="int" name="urstel"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Phone" 
 />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="email" name="email"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="E Mail" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="location"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Address" />
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
    </form>

</div>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: I would start creating a form with all possibel fields and depending on the call, hide the ome or other field from the HTML, either with jQuery or raw JS.
Anyway, it would be helpfull to see any code from you ...

Comment: this is like free coding service in subtle way

Comment: @plonknimbuzz my bad. I've got everything down in terms of the fields, $createsql etc. It's just a matter of the fields disappearing when a contact type is chosen. I've been told javascript would be necessary but I'm really not sure :(

Comment: @AxelAmthor code above. All pretty standard fields. Currently all functional. Just need the function of the fields being able to change when the radio box is filled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really easy with jQuery - I created a mock example just hiding and showing some values as you click the inputs.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  listenForInputChanges();
})

function listenForInputChanges() {
  $('#contactType >input').change(function(){
    console.log('val is '+$(this).val())
    switch($(this).val()) {
    case 'individual':
      $('#nameDiv').show();
      $('#companyDiv').hide();
    break;

    case 'team':
      $('#nameDiv').show();
      $('#companyDiv').show();
    break;

    case 'company':
      $('#nameDiv').hide();
      $('#companyDiv').show();
    break;
    }
  })
} // end inputChanger
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="form-group">
<label for="input" class="col-sm-6 control-label">What type of contact are you adding?</label>
 <div id="contactType" class="col-sm-10">
<input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="individual" checked> Individual
 <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="team"> Team
 <input type="radio" name="Contact_type" value="company"> Company</div>
 </div>

<div id="nameDiv" class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
 <input type="text" name="name"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Name" />
 </div>
 </div>

<div id="companyDiv" class="form-group">
<label for="input1" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Company</label>
<div class="col-sm-10">
<input type="text" name="comp"  class="form-control" id="input1" placeholder="Company" />
</div>
</div>

   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-md-2 col-md-offset-10" value="submit" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Hi Stacey. Damn this is exactly what I need! The problem at the moment is that when the radio buttons are clicked, nothing is happening. I do apologize for the silly questions :(

Comment: maybe the console is hiding the form!  When I click through the inputs, it selectively hides/show stuff - let me know if that still isn't working for you!

Comment: Ok really dumb question. Where is the JQuery function meant to go? Do I just open <script> </script> above the forms? I think thats the reason why its not working for me ha!

Comment: It's also been edited above to show my full code if that help explains anything

Comment: Hey no problem, everybody has to begin somewhere, we often assume everybody knows that stuff! Are you using these in an HTML page? If so, you can either attach it as a <script></script> function in the <head> section, but you'll need a body ready event - let me add that for you, ok?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Stacey. I've edited my code on the original question. I've probably just put the function/jquery in the wrong place. Could you please check it out? I feel bad for how much you've helped me, you're an absolute legend <3

Comment: Still unsure where the $('#contactType >input').change(function(){ goes. Feels weird to put it in <head> when my <title> and .css is there. Not sure where it goes and I'm sure thats the problem!

Comment: Can you just use an index.js file and link that in your head? Using functions inline is always sort of messy! I usually create a /libs folder or a /js folder and put the scripts in there. You can put before closing </body> tag too I think!

Comment: Turns out it was missing some script before the HTML. --> <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>. It's all working now! Thanks again for your help Stacey, all the best.